# React Native take useState in class Error: Minified React error #321

Tags: react-native, function, class

I am newbie to react native and

I would like to create a simple app.

using method function to create a TextInput

and make TextInput intergrate to Class export default class App extends React.Component

But unfortunately, I get Error: Minified React error #321, any idea how to make it???
Thank you very much

Full code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextInput, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

function Example() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('')
   return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        value={text}
        style={{ fontSize: 42, color: 'steelblue' }}
        placeholder="Type here..."
        onChangeText={(text) => {
          setText(text)
        }}
      />
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 24 }}>
        {'\n'}You entered: {text}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
  return (
    <View>
       {Example()}
    </View>
  );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call React component like this: `<Example />`

Here is your code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-hertz-vp2j6?file=/src/App.js:562-573)